# How do you determine what element of a form is the one responsible for an autopostback in ASP.NET VB?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, autopostback

I have a number of dropdown lists that I'm trying to chain together and they all have autopostback. How can I tell which one of the dropdown lists was the one responsibe for the autopostback? I'm very new to ASP.NET and visual basic so any suggestion, no matter how elementary, is appreciated.

Comment: Not to be a downer, but needing to do this might be a good sign you should refactor. I have been ASP.Net development for a long time now, and have implemented some pretty complicated stuff. However, I have never had to know which element caused a postback...

Comment: I appreciate the candor and experience. I'll rethink what I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [entire blog post](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2005/03/11/1886.aspx) about how to do exactly this.

Comment: I googled my hands off yesterday trying to find something like this. Thanks for making it look easy!